# Computing the unique triangles and edges from vertex connectivity of a Delaunay triangulation

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulation

I am currently studying triangular mesh generation in 2D and, in that connection, the Delaunay triangulation of a list of vertices $\{ v_1, v_2, ..., v_N \}$. The divide and conquer algorithm of Lee & Schachter (from their paper "Two Algorithms for Constructing a Delaunay Triangulation", 1980) constructs the Delaunay triangulation efficiently, but represents the triangulation in a way, which I need to translate to a different representation for my further computations. To be specific, for each vertex, $v_n$, Lee & Schachter's algorithm gives a list of vertices, $\{ v_{n1}, v_{n2}, ..., v_{n k_n} \}$, to which $v_n$ is connected by an edge of the triangulation and which are in counterclockwise order. What I would like to have is the following:

1. A table of unique triangles in the triangulation, i.e. an array of dimension $(\text{Number of unique triangles}) \times 3$ which in its $p$th row contains the three indices of the vertices making up the $p$th unique triangle.
2. A table of unique edges in the triangulation, i.e. an array of dimension $(\text{Number of unique edges}) \times  2$ which in its $q$th row contains the two indices of the vertices making up the $q$th unique edge.

I do not care about the ordering of the two tables. The only thing that matters is that the tables contain all unique triangles and edges.

It is straightforward to compute these two tables using a brute force approach. For example, to construct the table of unique triangles one could for $n = 1, 2, ..., N$ add the triangles $\{ v_n, v_{n1}, v_{n2} \}$, $\{ v_n, v_{n2}, v_{n3} \}$,..., $\{ v_n, v_{n k_n}, v_{n1} \}$ to a list ultimately containing all possible triangles of the triangulation, and then sort the list and choose the unique ones. This strategy, however, appears quite wasteful in terms of both computational work and memory to me, since all triangles will initially appear three times in the list. Unfortunately, I have not been able to come up with a better idea so far.

My question is therefore the following: How do I efficiently construct the above tables from the triangulation representation of Lee & Schachter?